# php adodb and fckeditor

Tags: php, mysql, fckeditor, adodb

I've recently switched to using php -> adodb library and quite like it, however I've noticed a problem with using it with FCK editor.

It appears that when putting content into FCK somewhere it's adding in \""\"\ everywhere and making a right mess...

Has anyone else expreinced this.

I'm not entirley sure if it's FCK or the adodb library - but I need to sort this out before progressing on..

Any help much apprecitaed.

Comment: Think I've worked out it's more adodb - So I need to know how to stop the library manipulating the data when saving i.e.  $r["Body"] = $_POST['FCKeditor1'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, is the data in `$_POST['FCKeditor1']` "correct" in the first place? Maybe the problem is related to [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) being on?

Comment: Yeah kind of write with the magic quotes, after that I'd posted another once I'd realised it wasn't linked with FCK - so full details can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267015/php-mysql-adodb - Thanks anyway

Comment: Just realised you was the person who helped me on the other post :-)